# R - using grid paths with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

Is there an up-to-date version of this document anywhere?

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Editing-raw-grid-objects-from-a-ggplot

I am trying to hack on some grobs, but can't figure out the correct format for gPaths.

Particularly interested in the second example, reproduced here:

```
library(ggplot2)
data  <- data.frame(Name = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"), y = c(100,200,300,400,200,300,400,350))
# you have to print before grob-ing
p = ggplot(data,aes(x=Name,y=y)) + geom_point()

# locate the lines
g <- # store the plot as a grob
  ggplotGrob(p)

grid.ls(g)

#notice 
#...
#panel-3-3
#    grill.gTree.383
#        panel.background.rect.374
#       panel.grid.minor.y.polyline.376
#      panel.grid.minor.x.polyline.378
#     panel.grid.major.y.polyline.380
#    panel.grid.major.x.polyline.382

grid.remove(gPath("GRID.gTree","layout","panel","grill.gTree","panel.grid.minor.x.polyline"),grep=T)
grid.remove(gPath("GRID.gTree","layout","panel","grill.gTree","panel.grid.major.x.polyline"),grep=T)
grid.remove(gPath("GRID.gTree","layout","panel","grill.gTree","panel.grid.major.y.polyline"),grep=T)
```

which, instead of removing the gridlines, throws this error:

> Error in removeDLFromGPath(gPath, name, strict, greppath, grepname, global,  : 
>     gPath (GRID.gTree::layout::panel::grill.gTree::panel.grid.minor.x.polyline) not found